# How to insert a row in a Pandas multiindex dataframe?

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a Pandas dataframe with a multiindex (Reg, Type, Part, IsExpired)-

```
Reg        Type      Part     IsExpired    Quantity
APAC       Disk      A        False        10
                              True         12
EMEA       Disk      A        False        22
EMEA       Disk      B        False        13
                              True         17
```

I want to make sure that every (Reg, Type, Part) tuple has True and False for IsExpired. E.g. I'd like to insert a row for (EMEA, Disk, A, True)-

```
Reg        Type      Part     IsExpired    Quantity
APAC       Disk      A        False        10
                              True         12
EMEA       Disk      A        False        22
                              True         0   <-- inserted row
EMEA       Disk      B        False        13
                              True         17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and then [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
In [11]: df2
Out[11]:
                          Quantity
Reg  Type Part IsExpired
APAC Disk A    False            10
               True             12
EMEA Disk A    False            22
          B    False            13
               True             17

In [12]: df2.unstack()
Out[12]:
               Quantity
IsExpired         False True
Reg  Type Part
APAC Disk A          10    12
EMEA Disk A          22   NaN
          B          13    17

In [13]: df2.unstack().fillna(0)
Out[13]:
               Quantity
IsExpired         False True
Reg  Type Part
APAC Disk A          10    12
EMEA Disk A          22     0
          B          13    17
```

Perhaps it makes sense to keep this as a column? Otherwise [stack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) it back:

```
In [14]: df2.unstack().fillna(0).stack()
Out[14]:
                          Quantity
Reg  Type Part IsExpired
APAC Disk A    False            10
               True             12
EMEA Disk A    False            22
               True              0
          B    False            13
               True             17
```

Comment: *Note: when doing stack/unstack there is often an alternative `pivot`/`pivot_table` method...*

Comment: Thanks Andy! I have a slight variant of the above question - For some special processing that I am doing, I am processing these records one row at a time. So one tuple of (Reg, Type, Part, IsExpired) at a time. So for the row in question, I end up with - [EMEA       Disk      A        False        22] where I can't use unstack/stack method. Is there a way to somehow insert a row for True here?

Comment: @VivekSharma if you're processing one time... I think either you should do this in batches (wait til you have many, then use pandas). Or just use python, and perhaps something like `collections.deque`. Or am I misunderstanding you? Why do you have to process them one at a time?

Comment: @VivekSharma (Also, creating DataFrames one row at a time doesn't scale well it's O(n^2) in time/memory.

Comment: In my problem description I left one level of index out where I have to fill some missing data but within the context of one (Reg, Type, Part, IsExpired). So it's processing a bunch of rows at a time. However, I used your suggestion to fill IsExpired values _before_ I created the multi level index and it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered just adding the relevant row? Since you're really just adding one cell of a value you could do it efficiently like this:

```
df.at[('EMEA', 'DISC', 'A', False), 'Quantity'] = 0
```

Comment: I've been using pandas for almost 5 years now. I can't believe that this is the first time I came across this need and just heard about `.at()` from your comment. Thank you!